# Core Data updating records does an insert instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Not sure if any one can help and yes I have gone through all the post of stack exchange and other places.

I have an app which sends data to the server when we pull down to refresh. At the time of refresh of data already exists in the core data it suppose to update the content but it seems to be be updating and creating a new entry at the same time. so when I go back to the table its got multiple entries for the same data.

here is the code that I am using

```
NSArray *fetchedDealDetails = [appDelegate getDealsInfoByID:testId];
if(fetchedDealDetails.count > 0)
{

    Deals *typeList = [fetchedDealDetails objectAtIndex:0];

    typeList.name = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"name"];

    typeList.id = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"id"];

    typeList.coupon_background_image = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"coupon_background_image"];

    typeList.use_online = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"use_online"];

    typeList.coupon_download_btn_image = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"coupon_download_btn_image"];

    typeList.deal_provider_id = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"deal_provider_id"];

    typeList.details = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"details"];

    typeList.feature_deal = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"feature_deal"];

    typeList.haveDeleted = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

    context save:nil];

}
```

Not really sure if there is anything wrong with this code. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This code doesn't create any new managed objects. They don't create themselves, so someplace you must be creating them, though maybe not when you mean to create them. Show the code that creates new managed objects and describe how that code is used.

Comment: I have checked all the code and only place I create them is when the user logs in and if there are no entry in the database the entry. The view controller that is causing the problem has no code to create a new entry. It just updates if the entry exists. No idea why this is happening. Will keep looking through the code. Thanks for your help

Comment: Like I said, managed objects do not create themselves. If you're getting duplicates, **something** in your code is creating them.

Answer (score 3):

Well i am not sure what your fetchedDealDetails Array contains.
When ever you wanna update core data object you should get that object first and then update it

for getting particular object to update

> NSPredicate *predicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"id= '%@'",[arr_temp valueForKey:@"id"]]];
>   [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
>
> Deals *typeList = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
>   error:nil]lastObject];

now assign the updated value to objectForUpdate

> ```
> typeList.name = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"name"];
> typeList.coupon_background_image = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"coupon_background_image"];
> typeList.use_online = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"use_online"];
> typeList.coupon_download_btn_image = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"coupon_download_btn_image"];
> typeList.deal_provider_id = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"deal_provider_id"];
> typeList.details = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"details"];
> typeList.feature_deal = [arr_temp valueForKey:@"feature_deal"];
> typeList.haveDeleted = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
> [context save:nil];
> ```

Comment: I have made sure the right object is returned when I am doing the update. Not sure why its doing this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: are you getting differential data when you are doing pull to refresh or whole data with old data?if you are getting whole data delete the database and reinsert it.